# Deleting a question to increase average question quality of a user

Tags: discussion, questions, deleted-questions, old-questions

I have recently seen that a lot of developers refer to their Stack Overflow account in their resume, and I would gladly join them, since I think, that Stack Overflow activity might be really representative.

As I was browsing through my questions, I noticed that I have some really old, pretty low quality questions. (I started on Stack Overflow when I was still a fresh programming student.)

Is it in any way harmful for the community or me, if I delete some of these low quality (possibly even duplicate) questions to increase the average quality of my questions?

Comment: You should read [this question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) and pay special attention to the possible effects of deletion. It is *in theory* possible to walk right into a question ban by deleting questions. Also note that you cannot delete questions that have positively scored answers.

Comment: @Louis Deleting questions isn't going to affect your post ban state.  Deleting the quesitons won't make bad questions stop counting, but they won't count against you any more by being deleted.

Comment: @Servy How do you interpret this? (Quoted from the answer on question I linked in my earlier comment.) "Additionally, deletion itself counts against questions if less than 30 days old when deleted if others have invested time into answering or moderating the question." I read it as saying that in some cases, the act of deletion has additional consequences.

Comment: @Louis The OP is talking about old questions from years ago, so that wouldn't apply here.

Comment: @Servy Right, it shouldn't be a problem, but in cases like these I prefer to provide the instructional pamphlet anyway. If the OP were to decide to *expand* the culling to newer questions, then they'd have been warned before doing so.

Comment: @Louis They have a pretty good history of quality questions.  Even if they did delete a few newer low quality questions they'd still be *miles* away from a ban.

Comment: I don't feel like questions you may have asked years ago would negatively impact your chances of landing a job if you also had more recent questions and/or answers that were high quality. Everyone was a beginner once upon a time, If anything it may show how much you've progressed.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's harmful to the community to lose any good quality posts. This includes *some* duplicates, but not all. If you feel like your posts are low quality or not helpful, you can pursue deletion. Asking some folks in a moderation-oriented chatroom, like the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chatroom, can help you determine whether others might find them valuable.

If the posts are valuable, but you still don't want to be associated with a post or posts, you can use the bold "[Contact Us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact)" link at the bottom of every page and ask the Stack Overflow team to disassociate a post from your account.

It will be as if another user asked the question from the beginning.

Comment: The premise of the question is that they're low quality posts, not good quality posts.

Comment: @Servy the answer lists how to handle that but allows for the possibility that others might find the questions valuable where the OP does not, which is a very common occurrence.

Comment: The way you handle them is by deleting them.  There's no sense going around disassociating a bunch of low quality posts that aren't actually useful to anyone; they can just be deleted.  Disassociation would be for if the posts were actually useful, contrary to the premise of the question.

Comment: @Servy As you can read, the post says if the posts are low quality/ not helpful, "**you can pursue deletion**". It then goes on to talk about what do (disassociation) **If the posts are valuable**.